# Use IFELSE in a function

Tags: r, if-statement

I am having a problem implementing the `ifelse` command. I would like to return only positives (or 0) outputs. For example, in the following equation `y=-50+(x^2)`, when `y<=0`, `y` should return `0`. When `y>0` it should return the proper output value. When I implement the following code:

```
test = function (x) 50+(x^2)
if(test <= 0) test <- 0 else y <-50+(x^2)
```

I always obtain 0.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```
test <- function(x) (x ^ 2 > 50) * (x ^ 2 - 50)

test(5)
# [1] 0
test(10)
# [1] 50
```

---

Another approach:

```
test2 <- function(x) pmax(0, x ^ 2 - 50)
```

Comment: It would be cheaper to store the result and test instead of calculating twice.

Comment: @Roland I completely agree, but I wanted short function.

Answer (score 1):

One solution

```
test = function(x) ifelse(0>(-50+x^2), 0, -50+x^2)

test(10)
[1] 50
test(100)
[1] 9950
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I know this was quite a beginner question 

Cheers